# What should be there in the blank - "altruistic" or "altruist"?

Tags: word-usage

I was to fill in a blank with proper word alongside its definition which was:

> Unselfish, more interested in the welfare of others than in one's own.

The answer given in the key was - altruistic. But I don't know why I am feeling that there should be "altruist" instead of "altruistic" as the answer because "altruistic" are "tendencies, behaviour". So, "altruistic" can't be used as a noun.

Comment: You haven't give the sentence that includes the blank. *Altruistic* is an adjective and *altruist* is a noun. Without the sentence in question, we don't know what type of word is required.

Comment: There wasn't a sentence. Instead there was the definition I provided and in front of it was a blank in which I were to write the word which fits.

Comment: In that case, this question cannot be definitively answered. Another possible choice would be *altruism*.

Answer (score 1):

> Unselfish, more interested in the welfare of others than in one's own.

This definition implies the defined word is an adjective. The first part of the definition, "Unselfish," is an adjective. The second part  does not define a thing, but defines a behavior or attitude.

In this case, "altruistic" would be the correct choice. "Altruist" would be defined as "**A person who is** unselfish and more interested in the welfare of others than in one's own."